# How to retrieve a value in stack in lua script?

Tags: c, lua

I'm embedding lua in my C application.
I'm pushing a variable into stack from C side, and want to retrieve it in the lua script itself.

What can I use to get the pushed value in the stack in the script file?

**C code:**

```
// ...
result = lua_load(L, luaByteCodeReader, file, "script", "bt");
lua_pushinteger(L, session_id);
if( lua_pcall(L, 1, 0, 0) != 0 )
// ...
```

In the Script I want to retrieve the **session_id** value

```
local session_id = ...
print "Start"
for i = 1, 10 do
  print(i, session_id)
end
print "End"
```

Comment: I'm not great at using the Lua API, but shouldn't you be calling `luaL_setglobal()` in order to access the variable using its name? (Or is that considered "evil"?)

Comment: The `session_id` value is contained in the multi-arg `...` (the first value in `...`) when passed back from C. The left-hand side in the above assign should pick off the first multivar-arg and store it into `session_id`.

Comment: How is this question different from your previous one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553060/how-to-pass-a-global-value-from-c-to-lua ?

Comment: It's not different, I had a problem retrieving the value at the script but now it is working fine thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you're passing parameters to the script loading, depending on your situation you may set a global value instead or call a function.

For instance, say you have a `on_init` function on your script:

```
function on_init(session_id)
   ...do something...
end
```

You can load the script as you're doing, then get the `on_init` function on top of the stack and call it with your parameter:

```
lua_getglobal(L, "on_init");
lua_pushnumber(L, session_id);
/* call the function with 1 arguments, return 0 result */
lua_call(L, 1, 0);
```

And it's a little bit cleaner.